# Ember: Nothing Handled the Action Error Occured

Tags: ember.js

So I'm following a tutorial to build an app on CodeSchool and I was trying to figure out how to write in a toggle when I noticed an error in the console basically saying that nothing is handling the action block I wrote in the template.

```
"Nothing handled the action 'toggleOption model option'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble."
```

The code below is the part of the template I'm having trouble with.

```
<ul class='list list--answer'>
            {{#each model.poll.option as |option|}}
              <li class='list-item'>
                <button class='list-item-checkbox {{if (eq model.option option) "is-selected"}}' {{action "toggleOption model option"}}>
                  <b class='srt'>Select</b>
                </button>
                <span>{{option.label}}</span>
              </li>
            {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This is the route associated with the template.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
store: Ember.inject.service(),
model(){
    const poll = this.modelFor('polls.poll');
    return this.get('store').createVote(poll);
},
actions: {
    toggleOption(vote,option){
        vote.toggleOption(option);
    }
}
});
```

Anyways, is there something I'm missing? I've been staring at this for awhile and I couldn't figure this out. The tutorial video I've been following and their completed code doesn't seem to run into this issue either.

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax issue `{{action "toggleOption model option"}}` it should be `{{action "toggleOption" model option}}`.

Comment: I just slapped myself on the forehead. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is not correct! [This is not a closure action so the action will bubble to the route.](https://ember-twiddle.com/99c21c302a7f5786e57f6e7988ef2e85?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

Comment: Thank you @lux. I removed that part from my answer